# Bootstrap 3 Gentelella navbar alignment to the right issue

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, gentelella

When removing one element out of 3 from the panel of a tile, the 2 elements left are not fully aligned to the right - theres 1 space left.

Before:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2yWf.png)

```
     <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a> 
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"> </i></a></li>
      <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></li>
     </ul>
```

After:
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9olI.png)

```
     <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
      <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"> </i></a></li>
      <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></li>
     </ul>
```

The CSS for panel_toolbox looks like that:

```
.panel_toolbox {
 float: right;
 min-width: 70px; }

.panel_toolbox > li {
 float: left;
 cursor: pointer; }

.panel_toolbox > li > a {
 padding: 5px;
 color: #C5C7CB;
 font-size: 14px; }

.panel_toolbox > li > a:hover {
 background: #F5F7FA; }
```

and the CSS for navbar-right:

```
.navbar-right {
 margin-right: 0; }
```

Can it be fixed?

Comment: Anyone, even a tip?

Comment: Same doubt here. I'm also having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rod, In the CSS, instead of:

```
.panel_toolbox > li {
float: left;
cursor: pointer; }
```

It should be:

```
.panel_toolbox > li {
float: right;
cursor: pointer; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a "pull-right" class on each element?

```
<ul class"nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
    <li class="collapse-link pull-right"></li>
    <li class="close-link pull-right"></li>
</ul>
```

It should helps you